# How to use JOINS, Inner Joins ,Outer Joins with Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join, outer-join

I am using the below query to get all loans data which have `Status "Active"`

```
select 
L.account_no as "LoanID",
m_client.id as "ClientID",
m_client.FULLNAME as "NAME",
m_client.FAMILYNO,
m_client.currentaddresshierarchyid,
m_client.guardianname as "Father/Husband Name",
o.name AS "Branch Name",
s.loan_status_id AS "LOAN STATUS"
from m_client
INNER JOIN m_loan L ON m_client.account_no = l.id
INNER JOIN m_office O ON m_client.office_id = o.id
INNER JOIN m_loan S on m_client.status_enum = s.loan_status_id
```

I want to extract all the loans which have `"Loan_status_id = '300'` Here 300 defines active loans which were due on "31-AUG-22".

If a loan's last instalment due date was "31-AUG-22", but is still active, it should also be returned.

The `m_loan_repayment_schedule` table contains the `duedate` column. Loan instalments are either 12,15 or 18 months.

How can I go about creating this query?

Comment: Put your conditions in a WHERE clause.

Comment: It would have been better to improve your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73880909/266304) rather than deleting it and asking again. It isn't very clear I'm afraid. Sample data and expected results might help, but please try to expand your description too. And did you mean to join to `m_loan` twice - the second one looks odd?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify conditions with your joins using `AND` but more easily you can specific the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Make sure you alias you main table `m_client`. Then add the fields with their aliases into the `WHERE` clause. This let's you filter on specific fields form specific tables.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.